# Injecting helper to DbContext in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm using asp.net Core 2.0. And my `DbContext` is like below. `AuditHelper` is a class for logging every database changes. So, I injected AuditHelper to `MyDbContext.cs`. But, I think that it is not a proper way? For example, when I create an instance of `MyDbContext`, I must give audit helper parameter like `MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext(null);`.
Is my `DbContext` style true or is there any better way?

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IAuditHelper auditHelper;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IAuditHelper auditHelper)
        : base(GetOptions())
    {
        this.auditHelper = auditHelper;
    }

    private static DbContextOptions GetOptions()
    {
        return SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(new DbContextOptionsBuilder(), "server=asdf; database=asdf; user id=asdf; password=asdf").Options;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        var audits = auditHelper.AddAuditLog(base.ChangeTracker);
        return (await base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken));
    }
}
```

Comment: With DI you don't need to create `MyDbContext`, the point is to have it created by someone else (by asp.net in this case), so it isn't a problem.

Comment: Why I don't need create MyDbContext and how? Can you explain more detailed? @AlexSikilinda

Comment: You inject `MyDbContext` in controllers the same way you inject `IAuditHelper` in `MyDbContext`.

Comment: But, I haven't got `IMyDbContext` interface. Should I create interface? Because for inject it, I need interface. @AlexSikilinda

Comment: You don't have to create an interface, check `Using DbContext with dependency injection`  from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext

Comment: That link is for classic injection of dbContext. But in `MyDbContext.cs` have auditHelper dependency. My problem is that. @AlexSikilinda

Comment: @HasanOzdemir once the context is registered with the container then there us no need to initialize it manually. the container will create the object graph when resolving the context for injection.

Comment: Thanks for replies both @Nkosi and AlexSikilinka.

Comment: Any particular reason for having the `options` parameter in the constructor but calling `GetOptions` for `base`?

Comment: I have 20 different API service. And I don't want write connection string 20 times. So, I've only write one time to `MyDbContext.cs` like that. If is there better way, I can change it. Because I don't know is this way wrong way? @Nkosi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the context and its dependencies are registered with the container

```
services.AddScoped<IAuditHelper, AuditHelper>();
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer("server=asdf; database=asdf; user id=asdf; password=asdf")
);
```

then there is no need to initialize it *(the DbContext)* manually.

The container will create the object graph when resolving the context for injection.

Note that the static `GetOptions` functionality can be moved to the `ConfigureServices` in start up as demonstrated above.

Which lets the context remain simple.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext {
    private readonly IAuditHelper auditHelper;

    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, IAuditHelper auditHelper)
        : base(options) {
        this.auditHelper = auditHelper;
    }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) {
        var audits = auditHelper.AddAuditLog(base.ChangeTracker);
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(true, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer @Nkosi. This reply lighten me about dependency.

Comment: But in this way, I must write connectionString 20 times for every API service project. Which one is right way @Nkosi?

Comment: @HasanOzdemir You could have the connection string in configuration file and load it on start up. no need to rewrite anything.

Comment: My structure is like that. I have 20 Web Api project and one class library project. Web Api projects have `startup.cs`. But class library hasn't got `startup.cs`. Which one of project should I write in the connection string and where? Because class library has no app.config or startup.cs. @Nkosi

Comment: @HasanOzdemir this is starting to spread into a new domain. Ask a new question that demonstrates what you explained in the last comment. Should be able to get more options from the community.